# How many connected covering spaces of $\mathbb{R}P^2 \times \mathbb{R}P^2$ are there? How many morphisms are there between them?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

This is one of exercises I have after a chapter about the fundamental theorem of covering spaces (see its [statement](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fundamental+theorem+of+covering+spaces#:%7E:text=In%20topological%20homotopy%20theory%2C%20the,is%20an%20equivalence%20of%20categories.)). Category $\mathrm{Set}^{\Pi_1(X)}$ there denotes the category of functors from the fundamental groupoid of $X$ to the category $\mathrm{Set}$. Note that a similar question came up here (e.g. this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259330/finding-a-covering-space-for-p-times-p?noredirect=1) and this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3592619/classify-except-isomorphism-all-covering-spaces-with-2-sheets-over-the-space?noredirect=1)), but they ask for the explicit computation of covering spaces that I don't need here and use results unknown to me. In particular, I don't have the result relating the number of subgroups of the fundamental group to the number covering spaces at my disposal. Moreover, I want a proof that uses the fundamental theorem.

I will now describe my thoughts. Since the equivalence of categories requires a functor to be fully faithful as well as there to be a bijection between isomorphism classes of each category (essential surjectivity), I think I need to prove that there is a finite number of isomorphism classes of $\mathrm{Set}^{\Pi_1(X)}$ and describe morphisms between them, which also should be a finite number. However, I don't know how to do it. Below are quick observations.

- Path-connectivity implies that the functor maps points of $\mathbb{R}P^2 \times \mathbb{R}P^2$ to bijective sets;
- morphisms in $\mathrm{Set}^{\Pi_1(X)}$ are natural transformations;
- there is a trivial functor in $\mathrm{Set}^{\Pi_1(X)}$ that maps each object to a singleton set;
- since there is an identity loop and both $F_1$ and $F_2$ are functors, natural transformation $\Phi: F_1(b) \to F_2(b)$ is required to be an identity function for some object $b$; then it follows that two functors are not isomorphic unless loops are mapped to same permutations for a fixed object;
- two functors are also not isomorphic if they map objects to sets of different cardinality since $\Phi$ is required to be a bijection for a natural transformation to be a natural isomorphism;

Then we could look at functors that map each object to a two-element set. Let's look at how they permute two-element sets with images of loops. I then see four possible functors. If we denote loops with elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, then they are a functor that maps all loops to identity permutations, a functor that maps $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 0)$ to a transposition of two elements and $(0, 0), (1, 1)$ to an identity permutation, and a functor that maps $(1,1)$ and exactly one of $(0, 1), (1, 0)$ to a transposition. Otherwise, there is inconsistency with group operation.

But then I think we can make infinitely many isomorphism classes just by mapping an object $b$ to a (possibly infinite) set and sending some loops to a transposition of two fixed elements, which reduces it to the case above, and this doesn't even list all of them. What is more, I only considered how a functor works for a fixed object $b$, but it can also be the case that loops at two objects $b, b^{\prime}$ define different permutations of underlying sets for respective loops, which results in infinitely many combinations. I also don't know how to describe natural transformations between sets from different objects, so I don't know how to approach the second question in my title.

And another point that really confuses me is the fact that the question asks to count *connected* covering spaces. The fundamental theorem works for disconnected spaces, and I don't see how this can help here at all.

Comment: You can cover $\Bbb RP^2$ with arbitrarily many disjoint copies of $S^2$ and/or $\Bbb RP^2$. So without the connectedness hypothesis, you can have infinitely many without even thinking. But you seem to be lost in formalism rather than thinking about the question in a concrete manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is path connected, then for any choice of $x\in X$ we have an equivalence $\pi_1(X,x)\simeq \Pi(X)$, therefore also an equivalence $\mathrm{Set}^{\pi_1(X,x)}\simeq\mathrm{Set}^{\Pi(X)}$. The left hand side is isomorphic to the category of sets with a (left) $\pi_1(X,x)$-action and equivariant maps. Denote by $\mathrm{Or}_{\pi_1(X,x)}$ the subcategory of sets with a transitive $\pi_1(X,x)$-action. The fundamental theorem tells you a bit more, namely that there is an equivalence of categories between $\mathrm{Or}_{\pi_1(X,x)}$ and the category of *connected* coverings of $X$. Note that any $G$-set decomposes as the disjoint union of transitive $G$-sets and under the equivalence of the fundamental theorem this corresponds to decomposing a covering space along its connected components.

In the case at hand, $\pi_1(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2$ and it is easy to check that there are only 5 transitive $\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2$-sets (up to isomorphism), therefore only 5 connected coverings (up to isomorphism).

Comment: And two of those are homeomorphic.

Comment: Your answer helps me a lot. I was unaware how connectivity is related to transitivity of group action in this case. I can prove it myself. I will probably accept the answer later. Also, isn't the number of transitive G-sets equal to $5$, since there are $5$ subgroups?

Comment: @Atin You are right, I fixed it.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't understand what you mean. In the orbit category the morphisms are $G$-equivariant maps, so $G/H$ and $G/K$ are isomorphic iff $H$ and $K$ are conjugate. In the case at hand $G$ is abelian, so we get an isomorphy class for each subgroup.

Comment: $S^2\times\Bbb RP^2$ is certainly homeomorphic to $\Bbb RP^2\times S^2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sure, but not as a covering, no? I.e. it is not a homeomorphism over $\mathbb{R}P^2\times\mathbb{R}P^2$, you have to switch the coordinates in the base as well.